# jna call to kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot in shutdown hook crashes the VM

Tags: java, jna, application-shutdown, jvm-crash

If a thread sets a shutdown hook using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook();
```

calls via jna the method:

```
kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (0x00000002, 0)
```

it crashes the VM. 
If I call the same method in the

```
WindowListener.windowClosing()
```

hook, the call does not crashes the VM.

Any idea why?

I can post part of the VM crash error report if it could be of any use.

edit: see the [VM crash report on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f61ddbc9c)

Answer (score 0):

Posting the VM crash report should help.

Answer (score 0):

Post part of the crash report on pastebin or the like maybe some can get some info out of that.

Well I don't know for sure but if you read the java doc for [`addShutdownHook()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

> Shutdown hooks run at a delicate time
>   in the life cycle of a virtual machine
>   and should therefore be **coded defensively**.
>   They should, in
>   particular, be written to be
>   thread-safe and to avoid deadlocks
>   insofar as possible. They should also
>   **not rely blindly upon services** that
>   may have registered their own shutdown
>   hooks and therefore may themselves in
>   the process of shutting down. 
>   ....
>   **Shutdown hooks should also finish
>   their work quickly**.
>   ...

these leads me to the conclusion that maybe calling such a method either needs services from the JVM that aren't available anymore or that this call takes too long.